# unable to find the folder to place my java package folder in tomcat 7

Tags: jsp

I have just downloaded and installed JDK1.7.0_11 and Apache Tomcat Server 7. I've googled and successfully configured them for the development of jsp applications. Now i have created a package which contains some of my defined classes. I don't know where to place this package folder in tomcat. Please help me out. Thanks

**package mypack**

```
package mypack;

public class Test{

    private String msg; 

    public void setMsg(String msg){
             this.msg = msg;
    }
    public String getMsg(){
             return msg;
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, mypack.*"%>

<%
Test t = new Test();
t.setMst("Hello World");
out.println(t.getMst());

%>
```

Comment: Please follow almost any Java web app tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If your package is a war file, you can put it in the `<tomcat_home>/webapps/` directory (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup).

Note that you can also put an "exploded war" in this directory (i.e. a directory containing the content of this war file).

**Edit**: from your updated question, I think the correct layout would be like this:

```
<tomcat root>/webapps/appname/
<tomcat root>/webapps/appname/WEB-INF/classes/mypack/Test.class
<tomcat root>/webapps/appname/index.jsp
```

Which tool are you using to write your files? If you are using a Java IDE like IntelliJ, Netbeans or Eclipse, you should take a look at how they can help you managing web applications. They can create this directory structure automatically, and even deploy it instantly on a tomcat server.

Please have a look at this tutorial on how to develop a [simple web application in Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html), it's very similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am talking about .class files. I am not working with war files at all.

Comment: Tomcat needs a webapp (either exploded or in a war file) in order to deploy your code. This includes a WEB-INF/web.xml file, possibly JSP files and one or more servlets. What code do you currently have?

Comment: @Nebelmann... i have edited my question. Please check my hello world code.